# How can I render API data into separate tables based on the value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I'm trying to create a simple NBA boxscore web app in React, but I am having trouble rendering the API data into separated tables for each game. I am trying to create separate tables with its own headers for each game based on the gameID value from the API. How can I achieve this?

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import ScoreCards from './ScoreCards';

const ScoreCardData = ({ gameStats }) => {
return(
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>gameID</td>
            <td>Players</td>
            <td>FGM/A FG%</td>
            <td>FTM/A FT%</td>
            <td>3PTM</td>
            <td>PTS</td>
            <td>REB</td>
            <td>AST</td>
            <td>ST</td>
            <td>BLK</td>
            <td>TO</td>
        </tr>
        {Object.keys(gameStats).map((gameData, i) => {
            return(
                <Fragment>
                    <tr key={i}>
                        <td>{gameStats[gameData].game.id}</td>
                    </tr>
                </Fragment>
                ) 
            })
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
 )
};


export default ScoreCardData;
```

Here is the code where I try to render the API data. I'm able to get a list of all the game ID's in one table, but I want to separate them according to gameID value so that I can display each table as a separate game. I also want to have the header row with all the stat names to be displayed for each table.

I'm basically just trying to create a simple NBA box score website, but I am having trouble actually rendering the data into a box score format. This is my first web application that I am creating, so I am very lost. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Here is the sample API data that I'm trying to render]
[Fullsize Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYz3F.png)

Comment: Your first set of `<td>` tags with header names should be `<th>` tags because you are trying to render headers, not data. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics#Why_are_headers_useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like this, if want to display separate table based on game id, we need to group the data first by `game.id` then loop through original gameStats data via `Object.keys`.

Demo link: https://codesandbox.io/s/8yjwk4nzv2

```
import groupBy from "lodash.groupby";

const ScoreTable = props => {
  console.log("props.gameStats ", props.gameStats);
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>gameID</td>
          <td>Players</td>
          <td>FGM/A FG%</td>
          <td>FTM/A FT%</td>
          <td>3PTM</td>
          <td>PTS</td>
          <td>REB</td>
          <td>AST</td>
          <td>ST</td>
          <td>BLK</td>
          <td>TO</td>
        </tr>
        {props.gameStats.map((gameData, i) => {
          return (
            <Fragment>
              <tr key={i}>
                <td>{gameData.game.id}</td>
              </tr>
            </Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const ScoreCardData = props => {
  return Object.keys(props.gameStats).map((item, i) => {
    return <ScoreTable gameStats={props.gameStats[item]} />;
  });
};

const gameStats = [
  {
    game: { id: 47820 },
    player: {},
    stats: {},
    team: { id: 57, abbreviation: "POR" }
  },
  {
    game: { id: 47820 },
    player: {},
    stats: {},
    team: { id: 57, abbreviation: "POR" }
  },
  {
    game: { id: 5000 },
    player: {},
    stats: {},
    team: { id: 57, abbreviation: "POR" }
  },
  {
    game: { id: 5000 },
    player: {},
    stats: {},
    team: { id: 57, abbreviation: "POR" }
  },
  {
    game: { id: 6000 },
    player: {},
    stats: {},
    team: { id: 57, abbreviation: "POR" }
  }
];
const groupedData = groupBy(gameStats, "game.id");
console.log("groupedData ", groupedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `gameStats` is an array of objects, and each object is a unique game, you can render a `table` per unique game by moving all of your logic within the map function. This is assuming you want an actual `<table>...</table>` per game.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import ScoreCards from './ScoreCards';

    const ScoreCardData = ({ gameStats }) => {
    return(
            {Object.keys(gameStats).map((gameData, i) => {
              return (
                <Fragment>
                 <table>
                  <tbody>
                   <tr>
                     <th>gameID</th>
                     <th>Players</th>
                     <th>FGM/A FG%</th>
                     <th>FTM/A FT%</th>
                     <th>3PTM</th>
                     <th>PTS</th>
                     <th>REB</th>
                     <th>AST</th>
                     <th>ST</th>
                     <th>BLK</th>
                     <th>TO</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr key={i}>
                       <td>{gameStats[gameData].game.id}</td>
                       ...
                       <td>{gameStats[gameData].game.to}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                 </table>
                </Fragment>
             ) 
           })
          })
         };


    export default ScoreCardData;
```